# Get the form-data key-values from the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, postman, form-data

On Postman, if there is a POST request and it is added in Body > **raw** a JSON file, one can access inside the code with **req.params.thatProperty**.

For example, we have this JSON in Body:

```
{
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "password": "secret"
}
```

in code:

```
app.post('/myUrl', (req, res) => {
   //here we can access the email by req.params.email
}
```

My question is, if the have in Body > **form-data** like in the following screenshot, how can we access the email on the request? There it's no `req.params` in this case.

[image]
But because I'm uploading a file and I'm using [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), I do have access to `req.file`. The problem is that in req.file is only information related to the image, nothing about the email.

the function starts like this:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('value'), (req, res, next) => {
    //how can I have access to the email from the request here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form data should be in req.body